# blank entries separately counted within a "partition by" clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working with Sql-Server 2008.
I have a table (MyTable) which contains two columns: **IDCustomer** and **PhoneNumber**. Some of the IDCustomers do not have a PhoneNumber, i.e. the corresponding PhoneNumber entry is blank (PhoneNumber is a varchar variable).

Here I give the first entries of my Table:

```
IDCUstomer    PhoneNumber
22               
13            911
10            118
8
17            112
....          ....
```

I am evaluating how many times every distinct Phone Number appears using this statement:

```
select 
PhoneNumer,
RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PhoneNumber ORDER BY PhoneNumber ASC)
FROM MyTable
```

I am intentionally not using

```
select PhoneNumber, 
count(PhoneNumber)
from MyTable
group by PhoneNumber
```

because in order to achieve my final result (which is not the topic of the question) I need to use the former expression.

My question is on the result obtained using the former expression (the one with the partition by). In fact, I would expect this result:

```
PhoneNumber     RN
                2  
112             1
118             1
911             1
```

because I know I will obtain it using the query with the group by.
But instead I get:

```
PhoneNumber     RN
                1
                2    
112             1
118             1
911             1
```

so it looks like the blank rows are separately and progressively counted. I have checked that the same happens with more than two blank entries. For istance, if I have ten blank PhoneNumbers the result of the first query is: ten blank entries in the first column and RN growing from 1 to 10 in the second column.

Hence, I would like to ask you if you know why the results are not the ones I was expecting. Am I not obtaining the expected results since I am missing something or making any mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: data type of phonenumber?

Comment: Without `GROUP BY`, you'll get one row in the result for each row in the source. Only the row number will be different if multiple rows have the same PhoneNumber, blank or not.

Comment: @Ashu PhoneNumber is a varchar(30)

Comment: You might have a mix of Null and empty string '' in the column.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have checked and there are no Null values, only empty strings

Comment: @DanGuzman But if I have two entries with the same, not blank, phone number, say 100, I get just one row: 100 | 2 and not 100 | 1 and 100 | 2 as it happens with a blank phone number. I am puzzled, may I ask you to clarify a bit please?

Comment: Just add a `group by PhoneNumber` to your query... as @DanGuzman suggested. You are misinterpreting how `row_number()` works I suspect.

Comment: Count() instead of Row_number() and use coalesce and distinct...http://rextester.com/FGYA99506  as to: "Am I not obtaining the expected results since I am missing something or making any mistake?"  rowNumber will number all rows from 1 to x for each partition so in the case of null phone numbers it's just going to have a separate row for each one.  you can either select the max(rn) or use a a count as it seems that's what you're really after...

Answer (score 1):

Try This it may helps you

```
;WITH cte(IDCUstomer,PhoneNumber)
AS
(
SELECT 22,  NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT 13,  911   UNION ALL
SELECT 10,  118   UNION ALL
SELECT 8,   NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT 17,  112
)
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(PhoneNumber AS VARCHAR(10)), '') AS PhoneNumber
    ,RN
FROM (
    SELECT PhoneNumber
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY PhoneNumber ORDER BY IDCUstomer DESC
            )
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY (
                    SELECT NULL
                    )
            ) - 1 AS Seq
    FROM cte
    ) DT
WHERE dt.Seq > 0
```

Result

```
PhoneNumber     RN
                2  
112             1
118             1
911             1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stick with partitions instead of GROUP BY then you will need to change ROW_NUMBER to COUNT(IDCUSTOMER) OVER (PARTITION BY PhoneNumber)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I have Sql-Server 2008 and the Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled

Answer (score 0):

As explained int he comments...

```
declare @table table (IDCUstomer int, Phonenumber varchar(8))
insert into @table
values
(1,' '),
(2,'     '),
(3,'123'),
(4,'456')

select 
    Phonenumber,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Phonenumber order by Phonenumber) as RN
from @table
group by Phonenumber
```

If you have `NULL` values in the data you can use this

```
declare @table table (IDCUstomer int, Phonenumber varchar(8))
insert into @table
values
(1,' '),
(2,'     '),
(3,'123'),
(4,'456'),
(5,NULL)


select 
    Phonenumber,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Phonenumber order by Phonenumber) as RN
from 
    (select isnull(Phonenumber,'') as Phonenumber from @table) x
group by Phonenumber
```

Comment: I have followed your suggestion but the blank lines are now counted once, i.e. I get an empty string with RN=1. However, I need to keep the information on how many times a distinct phone number appears in the table.

Comment: That's not what you said in the original post and in this case you just need to use count()